# Linear Model Assumptions

Tags: linear-model

[image]

Hi, above is the plot of residuals against the fitted value of a linear model. I am asked to determine if the assumptions for the linear model hold in this case. I don't think the constant variance for error terms holds in this case because there are some data points that are clustered while others are more spread out. I think the assumption that the mean of the error term is 0 holds because the most data points center around the band that is above and below 0. Are my answers and logic correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing you can try is to plot a histogram of the residuals, see if that looks normal.

Comment: There is virtually no evidence for heteroscedasticity in this plot.

Answer (score 2):

1. Constant Variance of Error Term (no Heteroscedasticity) **holds**. Regardless of the fitted values, you observe a constant spread around 0. Heteroscedasticity would look like this: [image]
2. Mean of the error equals 0 also **holds**, as you rightly point out.